# How to find the unknown $r$ from this congruence?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, integers

Find  with $0≤<624$ such that $2^{82}≅$ mod 625.

I have figured out that maybe we can use Fermat's little theorem to solve this question in which $r^{624}≅1$ mod 625. But I am kinda stuck in here as I'm not sure how to keep solving this question when the mod is larger than p in $a^p$. Can anyone leave me a tip? Any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: Easiest, I think, to use iterated squaring.  We quickly get $2^{16}\equiv 536$ and $2^{64}\equiv 366$ (all congruences $\pmod {625}$). which is practically enough to get the job done.

Comment: `\equiv` makes the $\equiv$

Comment: "I have figured out that maybe we can use Fermat's little theorem"  Can't.  $625$ is not prime.  But can use Eulers thereom that $\phi(5^4)= 4*5^3=500$ so $2^{500}\equiv 1 \pmod {625}$ which is not particularly useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3847038/242) $\,a\equiv b\pmod{\!5^k}\Rightarrow a^5\equiv b^5\pmod{\!5^{k+1}}\ $ if $\,k\ge 1\,$ so

$\qquad\qquad
\qquad\begin{align} \bmod 25\!:\,\ &2^3\equiv 8\\
\Rightarrow\ \ \bmod 125\!:\,\ &2^{15}\equiv 8^5\equiv 18\\
\Rightarrow\ \ \bmod 125\!:\,\ &2^{16}\equiv 36\\
\Rightarrow\ \ \bmod 625\!:\,\ &2^{80}\equiv 36^5\equiv -74\\
\Rightarrow\ \ \bmod 625\!:\,\ &2^{82}\equiv 4(-74)\equiv 329
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Fermat since 625 is not prime. You cannot use Euler either because $\phi(625)=500$. But $2^{82}\equiv 329 \mod 625$ which can be easily computed by repeated squaring.

Answer (score 0):

$\require{cancel}$Just to be different.

$2^{82}=4^{41}=(5-1)^{41} =\sum_{k=0}^{41} 5^{k}(-1)^{41-k}{41\choose k}$

Now $625= 5^4$ so for all $k\ge 4$ we have $5^{k}(-1)^{41-k}{41\choose k} \equiv 0\pmod{625}$.

So $2^{82} \equiv \sum_{k=0}^3 5^k(-1)^{41-k}{41\choose k}\equiv $

$-1 + 5\cdot 41 - 25\cdot\frac {41\cdot \color{red}{\cancel{40}}^{8\cdot 5}}2 +125\frac {41\cdot \color{red}{\cancel{40}}^{8\cdot 5}\cdot 39}{6}\equiv$

$-1+(\color{blue}{205}) -125\cdot\frac {41\cdot 8}2 + 625\frac {41\cdot 8\cdot 39}6\equiv$

$-1 + (\color{blue}{125 + 80)} - 125\cdot 164 \equiv $

$-1+80 -125\cdot 163 \equiv$

$79 - 125(165 - 2)\equiv $

$79 -625\frac {165}5 + 250\equiv $

$79+250 \equiv 329\pmod {650}$

.....

That.... probably wasn't the easiest way.