# If p is a prime number greater than 3, then what all remainders are possible when $(p^3+15)$ is divided by 18?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Please check if my solution is correct or not :-

Since p is a prime number and greater than 3 therefore it will be of form $6k+1$ or $6k-1$

$Case 1:-$ When $p=6k+1$

$(6k+1)^3+(6k+3)=6k+4$

$18k+4/10/16$

$Case 2:-$ When $p=6k-1$

$(6k-1)^3+(6k+3)=6k+2$

$18k+2/8/14$

Therefore there are 6 different remainders 2,4,8,10,14,16 possible

Comment: And have you found examples of each of those?

Comment: Examples are always key.  What do you get if you take $p=5$?

Comment: Wouldn't $6k+2$ correspond to $18k+2/\color{red}{8/14}$?

Comment: $$(6k \pm 1)^3 = 216k^3 \pm 108k^2 + 18k \pm 1 \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{18}.$$

Comment: @user2661923  [By $\rm \mu LTE$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3847038/242):  $\,p \equiv \pm1\pmod{2\cdot \color{#c00}3}\Rightarrow p^{\large \color{#c00}3}\equiv (\pm 1)^{\large \color{#c00}3}\pmod{2\cdot\color{#c00}3^2},\ $ so $\,p^3+15\equiv 14,16\pmod{18}\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, I know that.  However, the OP (i.e. original poster) used $~\pmod{6}~$ arithmetic.  I am trying to keep things simple, following through on the specific approach that the OP attempted, while illustrating that the OP should be engaging in $~\pmod{18}~$ arithmetic.  So, multiplying this out makes it easier for the OP to grasp the flaw in his approach.

Comment: Use direct calculation (using linked congruence laws) as in user's comment, or use  $\rm\mu LTE$ as in my prior comment.  For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: Note that the the proofs work for any integer $\,p\equiv \pm1 \pmod{6},\,$ i.e. integers coprime to $2$ & $3,\,$ so it is not really about primes $> 3\ \ $

Comment: @user2661923 There's no need to compute all those coefficients when expanding the cube. rather simply note Binomial Theorem $\Rightarrow (i\!+\!6n)^3 = i^3 + \color{#c00}3\cdot i^2\cdot \color{#c00}6n + (\color{#c00}6n)^{\large\color{#c00}2}(\cdots)\equiv i^3\pmod{\!\color{#c00}{18}}.\,$ Put $\,i = \pm1.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Again, I understand that.  However, I am trying to keep things simple for the original poster.  The idea is to illustrate the idea, as simply as possible, to someone brand new to number theory.  The idea is **not** to try to force the OP into immediately stretching his intuition in a way that the OP might not be immediately comfortable doing.

Comment: @user2661923 But likely the *point* of the exercise *is* to exemplify these generalizations, and they will be obscured by using brute force computation (vs. intuition to simplify such).

Comment: @BillDubuque That may have been the problem composer's point.  My point was to communicate to the original poster.  The communication should be shaped to  the target audience.  The ideas that you are broaching, are ideas that the OP may confront only **after** confronting the idea that he should be working in $\pmod{18}~$ rather than $~\pmod{6}. ~$ One step at a time.

Comment: @user2661923 I can't understand the fault in my solution , I understand what you did by expanding the whole equation, but what is the issue if I convert mod 6 to mod 18 ? Of all the 6 remainders 2,4,8,10,14,16 why only 14 and 16 survive ?

Comment: The fault in your approach is that you started out working in $~\pmod{6},~$ when the original problem involved $~\pmod{18}.~$  Attempting to convert an **intermediate calculation** from $~\pmod{6}~$ to $~\pmod{18}~$ is tricky, and should generally be avoided by a Math student new to Number Theory.  ...see next comment

Comment: Your categorization of primes as $~(6k \pm 1)~$ is *normally* good.  In this particular case, it is (**still**) good, because you can draw an immediate conclusion of the evaluation $~(6k \pm 1)^3, ~\color{red}{\pmod{18}}.~$ ...see next comment

Comment: Did you understand my first comment, where I multiplied out $~(6k \pm 1)^3~?~$  If so, do you agree with the Math?  If so, then you know that you must have made a mistake in attempting the tricky conversion of $~\pmod{6}~$ to $~\pmod{18},~$ and you can use the Math in my comment as a guide to finding that mistake.  Leave me another comment, if you continue to have questions.

Comment: Yes @user2661923 thanks a lot for the explanation , I do understand your first argument;  The reason I used this intermediate calculation step was on account of a practice problem I saw prior to this particular question in which the author had used intermediate remainder to arrive at the answer ;  Can I post that question and the solution the author has provided in the following comments, can you help me point out if there is an error in the author's solution as well ?

Comment: Wait.  Let me set up a **chat room**, and send you a comment that contains a link to the chat room.  When you get the comment, simply click on the link, and we can chat in private.

Comment: sure @user2661923, thank you !

Comment: Here is the [Chat room link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144852/math-problem).