# Finding cubic residues modulo $9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I wish to find all cubic residues modulo $9$, i.e., all invertible classes $A$ modulo $9$
such that the congruence $X^3 \equiv_{9} A$ is solvable. I have so far determined that the invertible classes are $1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8$. How do I now best determine those invertible classes for which the congruence is solvable and eliminate those for which it is not?

Evidently, one can just represent any number as $9k+r$, $0 ≤ r < 9$ which, on cubing, gives $729k^3 + 243k^2r+ 27kr^2 + r^3 \equiv_{9} r^3$, and then plug every allowable number for $r$ and obtain its residue..., but I am hoping to find a more efficient way.

Comment: Why not just cube each of the residues?

Comment: @lulu Yes, this is the method I suggested in my post?

Comment: I don't understand.  There are only $9$ residues $\pmod 9$.  Just compute all their cubes.

Comment: As a general matter, it's not so easy to decide if something is a cube $\pmod n$ or not.  Even if $n=p$ is prime, it's not as simple as it is for quadratic residues.  Here, of course, $9$ is so small that you really can do it in your head.

Answer (score 1):

We can take your idea about representing any number as $r+9k$ but instead consider every number can be represented as $r+3k$, with $r$ being its residue class mod $3$ so $0\le r \le 2$.

By expanding the binomial all other terms are divisible by $9$ except the first: $(r+3k)^3 = r^3 \mod 9$. So it turns out its residue class mod $3$ determines the cubic residue mod $9$ uniquely! That's simple enough to see by cubing $0,1,2$ we see $0,1,8$ are the only cubic residues mod $9$.

Comment: Special case of [LTE = Lifting The Exponent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3847038/242). $\ \ $

Comment: I believe that $0$ is not an invertible class modulo $9$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that if and only if $r$ is a cubic residue, so is $-r$. So given the set $\{1,2,4,5,7,8\}\equiv\{\pm1,\pm2,\pm4\}$ you need to run trials only on $1,2,4$. These cubes are easy to figure and the only additive-inverse pair you end up with is $\pm1\equiv\{1,8\}$.